# Windows console command to print 3rd column

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a scenario where I need to print particular column from Windows command line.

For example:

```
John was a Good Guy !
```

I need to print only `Good`.

In Linux we have many options, but in Windows I couldn't find any.

Comment: Are you restricted to the command shell or could you use PowerShell?

Comment: How do you figure that `Good` is in the third column? Are you staring from "column 0"?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ("John was a Good Guy !") do echo %%i`